# Gremlin and Neptune Db Set Property Max Length

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

What is the max number of values Gremlin and Neptune supports for set-based array properties?

I have searched Tinkerpop and AWS documentation but I am not able to find out what is the limit of set-based array properties in both of these graph dbs.

Please let me know if someone has any knowledge about it or point me to the documentation sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "one size fits all" answer to this question. It depends on the exact TinkerPop enabled graph database being used. The answer will be implementation dependent. The answer for TinkerGraph, JanusGraph, Amazon Neptune etc. will vary.

In the specific case of Amazon Neptune there is no fixed limit. The only limit is maximum available storage, and in the Neptune case, that is a big number, currently, up to 128TB. So with Neptune whether a set needs 10, 20, 100, or 3000 members, that's fine.

I am interested in the specific use case however as storing very large sets could potentially make some queries unwieldy to write.